# How to make `\iffalse \fi` into a macro name `\suppress`

Tags: macros

I often use `\iffalse` and `\fi` to suppress codes when troubleshooting. However, I wanted to repurpose this to suppress small pieces of tentative text which I can change later. For example, in the text below:

```
The quotes were sent last Wednesday, once we got the approval from the manager. However, it seems that they \iffalse were not very happy with the quote and wanted a lower price by 30 \%. \fi
```

I want the pair of `\iffalse` and `\fi` to be combined into a single macro like, say, `\suppress{}`.

So the code as given above can be rewritten as:

```
The quotes were sent last Wednesday, once we got the approval from the manager. However, it seems that they \suppress{were not very happy with the quote and wanted a lower price by 30 \%.}
```

How do I go about doing something like this?

Comment: just `\newcommand\suppress[1]{}` there is no point in using `\iffase` if you have already used a `{}`argument

Comment: See also `\@gobble`

Answer (score 1):

@DavidCarlisle provided what is probably the best (and simplest) solution. I already use something similar, but I call it `\memo` instead of `\suppress`.

Example:

It was a dark and stormy night\memo{needs revision, since this is set during June} in Trondheim.

The contents of `\memo{}` will not print. Anything following will print. Keep in mind that if you put spaces before  and after `\memo{}` then both spaces will print (double space) which is probably not what you want. You could do an `\@gobble` in the definition, but it is just as easy to omit space one the side of the macro.